# After mousedown event mouseover should get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to fire an event which on mouse key press should select textboxes and change its `border-color` to `black`.

How to keep sure that on `mousedown` event only `mouseover` event should get fired? Initially, it happens on `mousedown`: it drags and gets selected.

But after that `mouseover` gets fired automatically without hit of `mousedown` function.

Here is my code:

```
var clicking = false;

$(document).on("mousedown", "[id^='text']", function () {

  $(document).on("mouseover", "[id^='text']", function () {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'rgb(0, 255, 0)');
  })
```

Comment: It would be easier to show a solution to you if you had the HTML code to go along with the JavaScript code. Basically, what you do is that in `mousedown`, you set a Boolean to `true`, in `mouseup`, you set that Boolean to `false`, and in `mouseover`, you only run have the `if` loop `if ([Boolean]) { [...] }`.

Comment: It’s not exactly clear what you’re asking. Do you need [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)?

Comment: @Xufox He wants the `mouseover` event only to fire if the user has his mouse down on the element, kind of like a drag.

Answer (score 1):

create custom `mouseover event` and dispatch it after `mousedown event`

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown, false);

var event = new Event('mouseover');
function mousedown(e) {
    //debugger;
    button.classList.add("mousedown");
    button.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseover, false);
    button.dispatchEvent(event);
}
function mouseover(e) {
    //debugger;
    button.classList.add("mouseover");
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Leca277t/5/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He wants the `mouseover` event to be fired _only_ when the user has his mouse down on the element, kind of like he's dragging it over the element.

Comment: There's no `mouseover` event in your demo. There's simply two `mousedown` events.

Comment: Now, the `mouseover` event gets fired before the `mousedown` event.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what he wants! However, you should put that same code in your answer.

Comment: Thank you Nagesh for putting your efforts. See this  HTML code                                            <div>
    <p>Select textboxes  </p>
    <ul>
        <input type="text" bgcolor="#ffffff" id ="text324"class="tdClass"  >
<input type="text" bgcolor="#ffffff" id ="text325"class="tdClass"  |>
<input type="text" bgcolor="#ffffff" id ="text326"class="tdClass"  >
<input type="text" bgcolor="#ffffff" id ="text327"class="tdClass"  >
<input type="text" bgcolor="#ffffff" id ="text328"class="tdClass"  >
    </ul>

Comment: So 5 textboxes when i press mouse key and drag over them their border should become black  . So i did this code but it doesn't work

Comment: var isDragging = false;
    $("[id^='text']")
    .mousedown(function() {
        debugger;
        isDragging = false;
    })
    .mousemove(function() {
        
debugger;
        isDragging = true;
     })
    .mouseup(function() {
        
debugger;
        var wasDragging = isDragging;
        isDragging = false;
        if (!wasDragging) {
           $(this).css('border-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
        }
    });

Comment: put in jsfiddle and share link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/salok/36h4seeg/   Here it it is . When i press mousedown it should select till i moueup the key